# How to test @parcel objects as if they were sent across activities

Tags: android, parceler

When I unit test @parcel annotated models, I get the same object (even when using `Bundle`, or `Intent`):

```
@Test public void parcel() {
    MyObject myObject = new MyObject("123");
    Parcelable parcelable = Parcels.wrap(myObject);
    MyObject in = Parcels.unwrap(parcelable);
    // myObject == in (same id)
}
```

How to simulate the situation where the model is passed from one activity to the other, hence being recreated?

update: might need to use [this](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler/blob/master/examples/test/src/test/java/org/parceler/ParcelsTestUtil.java).

Comment: Thanks for ask that. I will track the answers, i am interesed y this too. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this [file](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler/blob/master/examples/test/src/test/java/org/parceler/ParcelsTestUtil.java):

```
@Test public void parcel() {
    MyObject myObject = new MyObject("123");
    MyObject in = Parcels.unwrap(ParcelsTestUtil.wrap(myObject);
    assertNotEquals(myObject.hasCode(), in.hasCode())
}
```

The test needs to be run with an Android test or Robolectric artifact.

Comment: Here's the source of ParcelsTestUtil for reference: https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler/blob/master/examples/test/src/test/java/org/parceler/ParcelsTestUtil.java .  You're correct, the key is to marshal and unmarshal the generated Parcelable through a android.os.Parcel.